# getting specific object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let arr=[
    {
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box6",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "21",
                "cartType": "fullCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                        "value": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                        "label": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks",
                        "value": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks",
                        "label": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "ECY Liquor",
                        "value": "ECY Liquor",
                        "label": "ECY Liquor"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Extra Earphones",
                        "value": "Extra Earphones",
                        "label": "Extra Earphones"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": "NewGalley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    },
    {
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box6",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "908SA",
                "cartType": "fullCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Cutlery Sets",
                        "value": "Cutlery Sets",
                        "label": "Cutlery Sets"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Dry Store",
                        "value": "Dry Store",
                        "label": "Dry Store"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "papercups",
                        "value": "papercups",
                        "label": "papercups"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "ECY Juice",
                        "value": "ECY Juice",
                        "label": "ECY Juice"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Duty Free",
                        "value": "Duty Free",
                        "label": "Duty Free"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": "NewGalley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    }
]
```

in the above array there are two objects i am adding objects into the array upon submit of a form.I do not need the entire object if the boxId property is same in the objects which are adding up.If the boxId is same the main array should only have the objects from the cartQuantityAllots array of the array which is getting added after that.how is it possible?if the boxId is different the new object can be fully added in the res array.Here in the res array two objects are there so i only need the objects in cartQuantityAllots to be added to the cartQuantityAllots of the first object in the res array.

the above array after operation should look like,

```
  const final=    [
            {
                "code": "756WP",
                "id": "full",
                "name": "Full Cart",
                "boxId": "box6",
                "cartQuantityAllots": [
                    {
                        "code": "21",
                        "cartType": "fullCart",
                        "typesOfItems": [
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                                "value": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                                "label": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks",
                                "value": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks",
                                "label": "Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "ECY Liquor",
                                "value": "ECY Liquor",
                                "label": "ECY Liquor"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "Extra Earphones",
                                "value": "Extra Earphones",
                                "label": "Extra Earphones"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
 {
                        "code": "908SA",
                        "cartType": "fullCart",
                        "typesOfItems": [
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "Cutlery Sets",
                                "value": "Cutlery Sets",
                                "label": "Cutlery Sets"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "Dry Store",
                                "value": "Dry Store",
                                "label": "Dry Store"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "papercups",
                                "value": "papercups",
                                "label": "papercups"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "ECY Juice",
                                "value": "ECY Juice",
                                "label": "ECY Juice"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                                "name": "Duty Free",
                                "value": "Duty Free",
                                "label": "Duty Free"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "index": "NewGalley1",
                "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hard to tell what the actual question is supposed to be here. Are you asking how you _find_ the object with the given box id, if it already exists? Well either loop over them and compare the box id until you find it, or use an array method such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: i have rephrased the question

Comment: I the res array if the boxId value is same the objects in cartQuantityAllots should only be updated taking it from the incoming object which is getting added to the res array

Comment: Still not much clearer what your actual question is now, resp. which part of this exactly is giving you trouble. Have you even _tried_ anything yet? If so, show it, and explain what exactly the problem with that was. (We are not here to write your code _for_ you, based on an "I have: ... I want: ..." question.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary object to store the boxId and array's item map.

```
function convert(arr) {
  const boxIdMap = {};
  return arr.reduce((newArr, item) => {
    const data = boxIdMap[item.boxId];
    if (data) {
      data.cartQuantityAllots = data.cartQuantityAllots.concat(item.cartQuantityAllots);
    } else {
      const copy = { ...item }; // use `item` if you want to modify the original array's items
      boxIdMap[item.boxId] = copy;
      newArr.push(copy);
    }
    return newArr;
  }, []);
}
```

```js
function convert(arr) {
  const boxIdMap = {};
  return arr.reduce((newArr, item) => {
    const data = boxIdMap[item.boxId];
    if (data) {
      data.cartQuantityAllots = data.cartQuantityAllots.concat(item.cartQuantityAllots);
    } else {
      const copy = { ...item }; // use `item` if you want to modify the original array's items
      boxIdMap[item.boxId] = copy;
      newArr.push(copy);
    }
    return newArr;
  }, []);
}

const arr = [
  {
    code: '756WP',
    id: 'full',
    name: 'Full Cart',
    boxId: 'box6',
    cartQuantityAllots: [
      {
        code: '21',
        cartType: 'fullCart',
        typesOfItems: [
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur',
            value: 'Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur',
            label: 'Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks',
            value: 'Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks',
            label: 'Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'ECY Liquor',
            value: 'ECY Liquor',
            label: 'ECY Liquor',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Extra Earphones',
            value: 'Extra Earphones',
            label: 'Extra Earphones',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    index: 'NewGalley1',
    imageGalley: '/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png',
  },
  {
    code: '756WP',
    id: 'full',
    name: 'Full Cart',
    boxId: 'box6',
    cartQuantityAllots: [
      {
        code: '908SA',
        cartType: 'fullCart',
        typesOfItems: [
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Cutlery Sets',
            value: 'Cutlery Sets',
            label: 'Cutlery Sets',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Dry Store',
            value: 'Dry Store',
            label: 'Dry Store',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'papercups',
            value: 'papercups',
            label: 'papercups',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'ECY Juice',
            value: 'ECY Juice',
            label: 'ECY Juice',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Duty Free',
            value: 'Duty Free',
            label: 'Duty Free',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    index: 'NewGalley1',
    imageGalley: '/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png',
  },
];

const final = [
  {
    code: '756WP',
    id: 'full',
    name: 'Full Cart',
    boxId: 'box6',
    cartQuantityAllots: [
      {
        code: '21',
        cartType: 'fullCart',
        typesOfItems: [
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur',
            value: 'Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur',
            label: 'Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks',
            value: 'Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks',
            label: 'Beverages - Juice & Softdrinks',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'ECY Liquor',
            value: 'ECY Liquor',
            label: 'ECY Liquor',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Extra Earphones',
            value: 'Extra Earphones',
            label: 'Extra Earphones',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        code: '908SA',
        cartType: 'fullCart',
        typesOfItems: [
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Cutlery Sets',
            value: 'Cutlery Sets',
            label: 'Cutlery Sets',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Dry Store',
            value: 'Dry Store',
            label: 'Dry Store',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'papercups',
            value: 'papercups',
            label: 'papercups',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'ECY Juice',
            value: 'ECY Juice',
            label: 'ECY Juice',
          },
          {
            key: '02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc',
            name: 'Duty Free',
            value: 'Duty Free',
            label: 'Duty Free',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    index: 'NewGalley1',
    imageGalley: '/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png',
  },
];

const newArr = convert(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr) === JSON.stringify(final)); // prints true
```